# How can I prove this inequality using this other one?

Tags: calculus

I already proved that :
$$e^{\frac{1}{n}} \ge 1+\frac{1}{n}$$
What I would like to prove now is that :
$$\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right )^{n} <e $$
It was suggested that I could use the first thing that I proved to do that.
How can I do ?

Comment: Raise the inequality you already proved to the $\;n$-th power!

Comment: @Timbuc The problem is to get rid of the case of equality.

Comment: @Timbuc Sorry, maybe is it because I'm not good enough in english/maths but I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @MarkBennet, I don't follow you. The OP stated he could use the first inequality to prove the second one. What am I missing here?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise, your first inequality (the one you said you already proved) is positive in both sides: raise both of them to the $\;n$-th power: what do you get? Of course, both sides are greater than one.

Comment: @Timbuc Actually I understand, I'm gonna try that thank you to you two.

Comment: @Timbuc The first inequality is $\ge$ and if you raise it to the $n^{th}$ power you sill get $\ge$. The second inequality is $\lt$ equivalent to $\gt$. So the power trick does most of it, but you still have to prove $\neq$.

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant now, @Mark. Thanks. Anyway, the first inequality is in fact sharp, so no problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the first inequality:
$$
\left(1+\frac 1{2n}\right)^{2n} \le e
$$

but
$$ e^{1/n} \ge
\left(1+\frac 1{2n}\right)^{2} = \left(1+\frac 1{n} + \frac 1{4n^2}
\right) >  1+\frac 1{n} 
$$
hence, as $x\to x^n$ is strictly increasing:
$$
\left(1+\frac 1{n}\right)^{n} < e
$$