# How can I prove this inequality by using this one?

Tags: calculus

If I already proved this thing :
$$e^{\frac{-1}{n+1}} \ge 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$
How can I prove that :
$$e \le \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right )^{n+1} $$
*It was suggested that I could use the first thing that I proved to do that.*
How can I do ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978739/how-can-i-prove-this-inequality-using-this-other-one

Answer (score 4):

You have $$\dfrac{1}{e^{\dfrac{1}{n+1}}} \geq 1 - \dfrac{1}{n+1}$$

so $$e^{\dfrac{1}{n+1}} \leq \dfrac{1}{1 - \dfrac{1}{n+1}} = \dfrac{n+1}{n} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{n}$$

then power both sides by $n+1$